# How do I add an json file inorder to integrate plot projects api

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin.forms, geofencing

I need to integrate plot projects API into my xamarin form app to receive location-based notifications. I have little experience using xamarin but I've never integrated an API before. As I follow the steps provided by plot projects, one of my first issues is adding plotconfig.json into the Assets folder. I tried to add it as an item but I don't see it as an option in the "Add New Items". I guess my question really is how do I make a plotconfig.json configuration file in my asset folder that looks like this:

```
{
"publicToken": "",
"enableOnFirstRun": true
}
```

Comment: They seem to have complete walkthroughs for Xamarin on their website.  And complete sample apps on their github.  What **specfically** are you having problems with?

Comment: one of my  first issues is adding JSON file into assets in xamarin form

Comment: Then you should probably edit your question to reflect that, and provide the necessary details about what you're doing and where you're stuck.

Comment: I hope this gives a little more info on what I'm trying to do and where I'm stuck

Comment: it's just a text file

Comment: so your saying JSON file is just a text file. Thank you so much man you probably just saved my job lol